# How to get data of webservice by json format?

Tags: json, vb.net, web-services

I try to get data of my webservice by json format such as below :

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols


' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")>
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function GetAllRss() As List(Of Rss)
        Dim db As EMCEntities1 = New EMCEntities1()
        Dim RssList As List(Of Rss) = db.Rss.ToList()
        Return RssList
    End Function

End Class
```

ajax :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WebService.asmx/GetAllRss",
       success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

In this case I get data by XML format?

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The webservice either needs to return the data encoded as JSON or you can parse the XML response using [jQuery.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

There may be a way to convert json to XML using librairies like "json2xml".

This could help : 
https://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

Additionnal information about XML and JSON conversion : 
https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html

Answer (score 0):

I use this ajax and solved

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WebService.asmx/GetAllRss",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```